# Necessary and sufficient conditions for weak convergence in $L^p(0,1)$, $1<p <\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

Let $1 <p < \infty$. Consider a sequence $(f_n)_n \subset L^p(0,1)$ and let $f \in L^p(0,1)$. Prove that $f_n$ is weakly convergent to $f$ if and only if the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^p(0,1)$ and $\forall x \in [0,1]$, $\int_{0}^{x} f_n (y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} f (y) dy $ (*). Discuss if the equivalence still holds removing the hypothesis that $(f_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^p(0,1)$.

Concerning the first part of the exercise, I reasoned as follows.

The direct implication is straight-forward since every weakly convergent sequence in a normed space is bounded. Moreover, from the characterization of weak convergence in $L^p$ spaces, one has that $(f_n)_n$ converges weakly in $L^p(0,1)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall g \in L^q(0,1)$, $\int_{0}^{1} f_n(y) g(y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} f(y) g(y) dy$ (where $q$ is such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$). Thus, fixing an arbitrary $x \in [0,1]$, we can choose $g = \chi_{[0,x]} \in L^q(0,1)$ and, by weak convergence of $(f_n)_n$ we can conclude that $\int_{0}^{x} f_n (y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} f (y) dy $.

The inverse implication is less obvious. My first idea was to use the dominated convergence theorem, but I cannot find a suitable domination for any arbitrary function $g \in L^q(0,1)$. I would like to use somehow the hypothesis regarding the integral of $f_n$, but I was not able to satisfyingly develop the reasoning.
Therefore, I proceeded in the following way. I know that for $1<p<\infty$, $L^p(0,1)$ is reflexive. By hypothesis, the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^p(0,1)$, thus there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ which converges weakly to a function $\overline{f} \in L^p(0,1)$. Being a subsequence of $(f_n)_n$, it is still true that $\forall x \in [0,1]$, $\int_{0}^{x} f_{n_k} (y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} f (y) dy$ and, following from weak convergence, we also have that $\int_{0}^{x} f_{n_k} (y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} \overline{f} (y) dy$. Thus, from the arbitrarity of $x \in [0,1]$ and from the uniqueness of the limit, we can conclude that $f = \overline{f}$. This reasoning can be iterated to a subsequence of $(f_{n_k})_k$ and thus the weak convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ can be deduced applying Urysohn lemma.

On the last part of the exercise I have few ideas. My guess is that the equivalence does not hold, hence I made an attempt to construct a sequence $(f_n)_n$ such that $||f_n||_{p} = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, I cannot find one which satisfies the integral property (*).

If anyone could give me a hint on how to proceed (as well as a check on the reasoning above), It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning looks good to me. For the last part, you can't have a sequence converging weakly without it being bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that a weakly convergent sequence must be bounded, but in this case I have an additional hypothesis on $(f_n)_n$, which is that $\int_{0}^{x} f_n(y) dy \rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} f(y) dy $ for all $x \in [0,1]$. However, I am struggling to find a suitable counterexample.

Comment: What about $f=0$ and taking $f_n$ to be functions supported on say $[1-1/n,1]$ with integral zero (but otherwise arbitrary)? Then your condition should be OK (why?!), but you can choose the sequence such that it is not bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I think I've come up with a suitable sequence. Let $f_n (x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1-1/n)$, $f_n (x) = n$ for $x \in [1-1/n, 1- 1/2n)$ and  $f_n (x) = -n$ for $x \in [1-1/2n, 1]$. With this choice of $f_n$ I have that $||f_n||^p_{L^p} = n^{p-1}$ for all $n$ (which is not a problem since I am assuming $p > 1$) and with  integral 0. However, this sequence is not weakly convergent (I guess it is sufficient to calculate the integral of $f_n$ against the characteristic function of the interval $[1-1/n, 1-1/2n]$, for fixed $n$, and show that it can't converge to 0). Am I right?

Comment: You must be careful with sequential compactness. In general, weak compactness of the unit ball does NOT imply weak sequential compactness. In the particular case of $X=L_p(0,1)$ the separability of the dual $L_q(0,1)$ implies that the weak topology of the unit ball of $X$ is metrizable. Therefore, it is indeed weakly sequentially compact.

Comment: Is it not the opposite? I mean, the weak topology is not metrizable and thus weak sequential compactness does not imply weak compactness (but the vice-versa is always true). I only used sequential compactness in my proof, if I am not mistaken. Anyway, I think the equivalence in this case follows from the Eberlein-Smulian theorem.